# Hangman Part 2 with Arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Well now in class we were assigned another Hangman Project with the use of Arrays and we have to generate " _ "'s.
I have successfully generated all the blanks when the user inputs the "wordAnswer".
My problem is that I cant figure out how to replace the correct guess char with the blank " _ ".

Here is my code for whole program and I know its not all complete.

```
import cs1.Keyboard;
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int correctGuess = 0;
        int wrongGuess = 0;
        int bodyParts = 0;
        char guess;
        boolean foundIt;
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a word for the other user to guess!");
        String wordAnswer = Keyboard.readString();
        char[] chars = wordAnswer.toCharArray();
        char[] blanks = new char[wordAnswer.length()];

        System.out.println("You have 6 attempts to guess the word!");
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < wordAnswer.length(); i++) {
                System.out.print(" _ ");
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter in your guess!");
            guess = Keyboard.readChar();
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                if (guess == chars[i]) {
                    blanks[i] = guess;
                    foundIt = true;
                }
            }
        } while (correctGuess < wordAnswer.length() && wrongGuess != 6); {
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You have solved the word!");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that you have to use a for loop to be able to change the blank to the correct guessed letter but when you run the program and enter in your the correct guess the blank does not change into the correct letter. 
Here is my OutPut

```
 Welcome to Hangman!
Please enter a word for the other user to guess!
program
You have 6 attempts to guess the word!
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
p
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
r
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
o
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
g
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
r
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
a
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
m
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
```

What I am expecting is!!

```
    Welcome to Hangman!
Please enter a word for the other user to guess!
program
You have 6 attempts to guess the word!
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
p
 p  _  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
r
 p  r  _  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
o
 p  r  o  _  _  _  _ Please enter in your guess!
```

etc...

This is what I have but tips and help would be very appreciative!!

```
System.out.println("Please enter in your guess!");
        guess = Keyboard.readChar();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (guess == chars[i]) {
                blanks[i] = guess;
                foundIt = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful problem description. *How* is it "not working"? Compile error? Runtime exception? What is the error/exception? Did you Google it to make an effort to understand what it is and why it's happening? Or is it incorrect behavior? What happened? What did you expect to happen? Be more detailed.

Comment: Still not very clear.  Are you expecting to see `p _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _` on your second line, `p r _ _ _ _ _ ` on the third, etc?

Comment: Okay I have updated it and I dont think I really can be more specific. What im looking for is for the correct guessed letter to replace the " _ " blanks.

Comment: All you need is to initially fill `blanks` array with `_` and always print its members, instead of hard-coded underscores.

Answer (score 0):

After the line

```
char[] blanks = new char[wordAnswer.length()];
```

add the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordAnswer.length(); i++) {
    blanks[i] = '_';
}
```

Then, instead of `System.out.print(" _ ")`, do `System.out.print(" " + blanks[i] + " ");`

Just so you know, you need to fix what comes after the `do ... while` loop. It will incorrectly tell the person that they have successfully solved the word, even if they were unsuccessful. You also don't need the `{ ... }` after the while. Also, your `foundIt` variable isn't doing anything yet, although you will need it to handle incorrect guesses once you get to that point..

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Just a couple of adjustments.

Right after

```
char[] blanks = new char[wordAnswer.length()];
```

add

```
Arrays.fill(blanks, "_");
```

or, if you are not allowed to use `Arrays` class, then do it the old way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < blanks.length; i++) {
   blanks[i] = " _ ";
}
```

**AND**

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < wordAnswer.length(); i++) {
   System.out.print(" _ ");
}
```

put

```
for (int i = 0; i < blanks.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(blanks[i]);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for that tip but what about replacing the "_" blanks with the correct guessed letters?